# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Store

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am developing Outlook add-ins which populates all the available shared mailboxes in to combo box and sends email using the selected mailbox.

When I select the mail account from combo box, I get error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Store'

Following is the code.
Populate combo box.

```
private void MailBoxOptions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application =
        new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Stores stores = ns.Stores;
    foreach (var store in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.Stores
        .Cast<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Store>()
        .Where(c => c.ExchangeStoreType == 
                      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlExchangeStoreType.olExchangeMailbox))
    {
        if (store != null)
        {
            mailBoxes.Items.Add(store.DisplayName);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You don't have access to any shared mail-inbox.");
        }
    }
}
```

Code for Combo box

```
public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedStore = (Store)mailBoxes.SelectedItem;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you debug your code? Because there are so many uses of the store type which is not identifying which code is responsible for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `mailBoxes` is your ComboBox then

```
mailBoxes.Items.Add(store.DisplayName);
```

Only adds the `DisplayName`-strings to the ComboBox. Your problem now is to turn those back into the mailbox.
In case there cannot be two mailboxes with the same name I suggest a `Dictionary`

```
private Dictionary<string, Store> storeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Store>();

private void MailBoxOptions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Stores stores = ns.Stores;
    foreach (var store in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.Stores.Cast<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Store>().Where(c => c.ExchangeStoreType == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlExchangeStoreType.olExchangeMailbox))
    {
        if (store != null)
        {
            mailBoxes.Items.Add(store.DisplayName);
            storeDictionary.Add(store.DisplayName, store); // Add the items to the dictionary
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You don't have access to any shared mail-inbox.");
        }
    }
}
```

Then get the `Store` from the Dictionary

```
public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!mailBoxes.SelectedItem is string selectedString))
        return;

    bool successful = storeDictionary.TryGetValue(selectedString, out Store selectedStore);
    if(!successful)
    {
        return;
    }
    // Access selectedStore here
}
```

Comment: Hi IDarkCoder, thank you for your reply. Now it is showing error at `mailBoxes.SelectedItem` that `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' `

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to parse the selected item to a string. I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the most useful answer by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

With `mailBoxes.Items.Add(store.DisplayName);` you are adding the display name of the store as `string` to the ComboBox. And that's exacly what you get in return with `mailBoxes.SelectedItem`. Of course you cannot cast this string to `Store`.

You could wrap the store in a display class

```
public class StoreDisplay
{
    public StoreDisplay(Store store)
    {
        this.Store = store;
    }

    public Store Store { get; }

    public override string ToString() ==> Store.DisplayName;
}
```

Then you can add items to the ComboBox with

```
mailBoxes.Items.Add(new StoreDisplay(store));
```

Because `ToString` has been overridden, the ComboBox will show the `DisplayName` or every store item.

Finally, you can retrive the store with

```
var selectedStore = ((StoreDisplay)mailBoxes.SelectedItem)?.Store;
if (selectedStore != null) {
    ...
}
```

You can also try to add the `Store` objects directly to the ComboBox; however, I don't know if they will display correctly.

---

A side note: If you have conflicting type names or if you simply want shorter namespace references, you can use namespace aliases

```
using MsOl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using AppSession = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session;
```

and use it like this

```
var application = new MsOl.Application();
MsOl.NameSpace ns = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Stores stores = ns.Stores;
foreach (var store in AppSession.Stores
    .Cast<MsOl.Store>()
    .Where(c => c.ExchangeStoreType == MsOl.OlExchangeStoreType.olExchangeMailbox))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can access `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.Stores.Cast<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Store>()
   .Where(c => c.ExchangeStoreType == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlExchangeStoreType.olExchangeMailbox)` 
in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`,

you could try:

```
var selectedStore = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.Stores.Cast<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Store>()
   .Where(c => c.ExchangeStoreType == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlExchangeStoreType.olExchangeMailbox)
   .SingleOrDefault(x => x.DisplayName == mailBoxes.SelectedItem);
```